# read a json file in swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift

hi guys I have a json file in my swift project and I want to read this file and use its content to draw stuff. I created a controller where I have the following.

```
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonData = getJSON("hls.json")

        println(jsonData)

        let jsonDataResult = parseJSON(jsonData)

        println("\(jsonDataResult)")
    }

    func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
        return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
    }

    func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary{
        var error: NSError?
        var boardsDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

        return boardsDictionary
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it says: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at the getJSOn function. I have the file called hls.json in my app directory where all my swift files are so I don't know if its because it can't read it or what.. Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: - first, verify the result of JSONObjectWithData is not nil. Then, remember that json string can be a dictionary or array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new at this JSON stuff. However, I think I know what the problem is. You said you are trying to read the file called hls.json in your **app directory**, but looking at your getJSON function suggests that you're trying to grab the data from the internet.

(Correct me if I'm wrong) I believe what you're doing right now is trying to get the JSON data from a website called "hls.json" rather than trying to access a file in your computer.

Because a website with the url "hls.json" doesn't exist, calling getJSON("hls.json") will always return nil.

The way to solve this is to use

`let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hls",ofType:"json")`

and then using

`if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!,
        options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached,
        error:&readError) {
        success(data: data)
      }`

to act as the data you do for the parse JSON.

Hope that helps. Again, I'm also new at this so I'm not absolutely sure ;P

Answer (score 1):

You are force unwrapping a nil using exclamation marks in `getJSON()`. And this is because your NSURL might be nil due to the way its created.

You might need to change your `getJSON()` function to get the URL for your file correctly as follows:

```
func getJSON(fileName: String, extn: String) -> NSData?
{
    if let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: extn) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL) {
            return data
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Note that this function may return nil. Hence the return signature is `NSData?`.

So you have to unwrap the `NSData?` coming out of `getJSON` function before you can call your `parseJSON` function, as `parseJSON` takes a non-optional `NSData` as the argument.

The unwrap can be done with another `if let` statement as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let jsonData = getJSON("hls", "json") {
        println(jsonData)
        let jsonDataResult = parseJSON(jsonData)
        println("\(jsonDataResult)")
    }
}
```

Since the question is about the nil unwrapping error on `getJSON()`, I have not looked at the correctness of `parseJSON()` function.

Comment: Thanks! this works almost.. Just the parseJSON seems also to be broke.. I have that like this now   if let jsonDataResult = parseJSON(jsonData!) {
            println("\(jsonDataResult)")
        } and it says that the bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type. So when I explicitly say let it be anyobject the error goes away but then the function parseJSON tells me the same error as the other function before..

Comment: Once you do `if let jsonData = getJSON("hls", "json")`, the conditional value returned from `getJSON()` is unwrapped into `jsonData`. This means you can not force-unwrap `jsonData` with an exclamation mark like in your previous comment. What happens when you change `jsonData!` to `jsonData` ?

Comment: It says value of optional type NSDATA? not unwrapped did you mean to use ! or ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on which line exactly the error is on, and which variable? Since `jsonData` is a non-conditional, you can not use `jsonData!`, so the error is somewhere else.

Comment: This is how the error pops up when I add a question mark instead of the ! http://cl.ly/image/1M0x283Z1I1r

Comment: My `?` was part of part of my question to you. :)  You just have to remove the `!`, leaving `jsonData` as is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70347/discussion-between-codingminion-and-reshad).

Comment: Your code is different from mine as per the screen shot. You have not used `if let` as I had in my reply. `let jsonData = getJSON("hls", "json")` is not the same as `if let jsonData = getJSON("hls", "json"){ .. }`. May I recommend you reading up on optionals in Swift?

Comment: The problem right now is in this boardsDictionary.. it tells me it finds nil while unwrapping an optional value..